# No obtengo el valor del input

Tags: javascript, html5, dom

Quiero obtener lo que hay en el input una vez se presione la tecla enter

```js
function getInput() {
  let inp = document.getElementsByName('palabrasUsuario').value;
}
```

```html
<form name="pForm">
    <input id="inpt" type="text" name="palabrasUsuario" value="Ingresa tus palabras">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes el evento `submit` para los formularios. Es decir, cuando se aprieta el enter o se envia el form mediante un botón este evento se va a ejecutar y se puede escuchar este evento y obtener los datos del form.

He usado `getElementById` en vez de `getElementsByName` porque solo quieres obtener el dato de un input. Si tuvieras mas elementos con el mismo atributo `name` seria mas adecuado usar `getElementsByName` ya que devuelve una colección de elementos.

```js
function getInput() {
 return document.getElementById('inpt').value;
}

document.getElementById('pForm').addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const value = getInput();
  alert(value);
});
```

```html
<form name="pForm" id="pForm">
    <input id="inpt" type="text" name="palabrasUsuario" value="Ingresa tus palabras">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByName te devuelve un array, entonces deberias hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
let inp = document.getElementsByName('palabrasUsuario')[0].value;
```

o usar getElementById(), de la siguiente forma:

```
let inp = document.getElementById('inpt').value;
```